# Storing and querying a date as JSON sting in Firestore, is it a good practice?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

is it a good practice if you are storing and querying a date as a string that has the output of `Date.toJSON`?

It can be data for example from another service.

Are there any query issues or limitations? From my tests comparison on `where` worked as expected but I fear I might miss some gotcha.

Comment: I'm more curious than anything, but why bother going from a json string rather than an integer?

Comment: As far as string values go, the `toJSON()` format (`2019-05-28T23:23:46.933Z`) is probably best. But that said, I'd still prefer the date format for the reasons Doug outlined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't do that.  It will limit what you can do with that date value.

The best practice is to use Firestore's native timestamp type, which you can target easily in security rules.  If for some reason that's not going to work, you should use an integer, usually milliseconds since epoch.